# Cubic spline for non-monotonic data (not a 1d function)

Tags: python, interpolation

I have a curve as shown below:
[image]

The x coordinates and the y coordinates for this plot are:
`path_x= (4.0, 5.638304088577984, 6.785456961280076, 5.638304088577984, 4.0)`
`path_y =(0.0, 1.147152872702092, 2.7854569612800755, 4.423761049858059, 3.2766081771559668)`

And I obtained the above picture by:

```
x_min =min(path_x)-1
x_max =max(path_x)+1
y_min =min(path_y)-1
y_max =max(path_y)+1

num_pts = len(path_x)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
#fig = plt.figure()
plt.suptitle("Curve and the boundary")
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax.set_xlim([min(x_min,y_min),max(x_max,y_max)])
ax.set_ylim([min(x_min,y_min),max(x_max,y_max)])
ax.plot(path_x,path_y)
```

Now my intention is to draw a smooth curve using cubic splines. But looks like for  cubic splines you need the `x coordinates` to be on ascending order. whereas in this case, neither `x values` nor `y values` are in the ascending order.
Also this is not a function. That is an `x value` is mapped with more than one element in the range.

I also went over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616993/interpolating-1d-nonfunction-data-points) post. But I couldn't figure out a proper method to solve my problem.

I really  appreciate your help in this regard

Comment: Parametrize the curve. You can separate it as x(t) and y(t), which are splineable

Comment: @gune Please don't forget to put a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67461181/941531), I deleted it to make some modifications, and undeleted afterwards, so I'm concerned that you haven't been notified about my undeleted updated answer.

Comment: you might find some hints in the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279060/splines-with-python-using-control-knots-and-endpoints

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can always parameterize any curve/surface with an arbitrary (and linear!) parameter.

For example, define `t` as a parameter such that you get `x=x(t)` and `y=y(t)`. Since `t` is arbitrary, you can define it such that at `t=0`, you get your first `path_x[0],path_y[0]`, and at `t=1`, you get your last pair of coordinates, `path_x[-1],path_y[-1]`.

Here is a code using `scipy.interpolate`

```
import numpy
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path_x = numpy.asarray((4.0, 5.638304088577984, 6.785456961280076, 5.638304088577984, 4.0),dtype=float)
path_y = numpy.asarray((0.0, 1.147152872702092, 2.7854569612800755, 4.423761049858059, 3.2766081771559668),dtype=float)

# defining arbitrary parameter to parameterize the curve
path_t = numpy.linspace(0,1,path_x.size)

# this is the position vector with
# x coord (1st row) given by path_x, and
# y coord (2nd row) given by path_y
r = numpy.vstack((path_x.reshape((1,path_x.size)),path_y.reshape((1,path_y.size))))

# creating the spline object
spline = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(path_t,r,kind='cubic')

# defining values of the arbitrary parameter over which
# you want to interpolate x and y
# it MUST be within 0 and 1, since you defined
# the spline between path_t=0 and path_t=1
t = numpy.linspace(numpy.min(path_t),numpy.max(path_t),100)

# interpolating along t
# r[0,:] -> interpolated x coordinates
# r[1,:] -> interpolated y coordinates
r = spline(t)

plt.plot(path_x,path_y,'or')
plt.plot(r[0,:],r[1,:],'-k')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

With output

[image: cubic spline in 2d]

Comment: Thank you very much for the code with detailed explanations! Yes this will work

Answer (score 1):

For non-ascending `x` splines can be easily computed if you make both `x` and `y` functions of another parameter `t`: `x(t)`, `y(t)`.

In your case you have 5 points so `t` should be just enumeration of these points, i.e. `t = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4` for 5 points.

So if `x = [5, 2, 7, 3, 6]` then `x(t) = x(0) = 5`, `x(1) = 2`, `x(2) = 7`, `x(3) = 3`, `x(4) = 6`. Same for `y`.

Then compute spline function for both `x(t)` and `y(t)`. Afterwards compute values of splines in all many intermediate `t` points. Lastly just use all calculated values `x(t)` and `y(t)` as a function `y(x)`.

Once before I implemented cubic spline computation from scratch using Numpy, so I use this code in my example below if you don't mind (it could be useful for you to learn about spline math), replace with your library functions. Also in my code you can see `numba` lines commented out, if you want you can use these [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) annotations to speed up computation.

You have to look at `main()` function at the bottom of code, it shows how to compute and use `x(t)` and `y(t)`.

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow67460967#main.py)

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Solves linear system given by Tridiagonal Matrix
# Helper for calculating cubic splines
#@numba.njit(cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def tri_diag_solve(A, B, C, F):
    n = B.size
    assert A.ndim == B.ndim == C.ndim == F.ndim == 1 and (
        A.size == B.size == C.size == F.size == n
    ) #, (A.shape, B.shape, C.shape, F.shape)
    Bs, Fs = np.zeros_like(B), np.zeros_like(F)
    Bs[0], Fs[0] = B[0], F[0]
    for i in range(1, n):
        Bs[i] = B[i] - A[i] / Bs[i - 1] * C[i - 1]
        Fs[i] = F[i] - A[i] / Bs[i - 1] * Fs[i - 1]
    x = np.zeros_like(B)
    x[-1] = Fs[-1] / Bs[-1]
    for i in range(n - 2, -1, -1):
        x[i] = (Fs[i] - C[i] * x[i + 1]) / Bs[i]
    return x
    
# Calculate cubic spline params
#@numba.njit(cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def calc_spline_params(x, y):
    a = y
    h = np.diff(x)
    c = np.concatenate((np.zeros((1,), dtype = y.dtype),
        np.append(tri_diag_solve(h[:-1], (h[:-1] + h[1:]) * 2, h[1:],
        ((a[2:] - a[1:-1]) / h[1:] - (a[1:-1] - a[:-2]) / h[:-1]) * 3), 0)))
    d = np.diff(c) / (3 * h)
    b = (a[1:] - a[:-1]) / h + (2 * c[1:] + c[:-1]) / 3 * h
    return a[1:], b, c[1:], d

# Spline value calculating function, given params and "x"
#@numba.njit(cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def func_spline(x, ix, x0, a, b, c, d):
    dx = x - x0[1:][ix]
    return a[ix] + (b[ix] + (c[ix] + d[ix] * dx) * dx) * dx

# Compute piece-wise spline function for "x" out of sorted "x0" points
#@numba.njit([f'f{ii}[:](f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:])' for ii in (4, 8)],
#    cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def piece_wise_spline(x, x0, a, b, c, d):
    xsh = x.shape
    x = x.ravel()
    ix = np.searchsorted(x0[1 : -1], x)
    y = func_spline(x, ix, x0, a, b, c, d)
    y = y.reshape(xsh)
    return y

def main():
    x0 = np.array([4.0, 5.638304088577984, 6.785456961280076, 5.638304088577984, 4.0])
    y0 = np.array([0.0, 1.147152872702092, 2.7854569612800755, 4.423761049858059, 3.2766081771559668])
    t0 = np.arange(len(x0)).astype(np.float64)
    plt.plot(x0, y0)
    vs = []
    for e in (x0, y0):
        a, b, c, d = calc_spline_params(t0, e)
        x = np.linspace(0, t0[-1], 100)
        vs.append(piece_wise_spline(x, t0, a, b, c, d))
    plt.plot(vs[0], vs[1])
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

[image]